# How To Toggle Variable Literal(Value) Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at  <kbd>[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/zR2VM/)</kbd> and let me know how I can toggle varible value from "`ecolo`" to "`econo`" using jQuery?

```
<button id="model">Toggle Query</button> 
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
var qtype= "econo";
$("#model").on("click", function () {
    qtype= "ecolo";
    $("#result").html(qtype);
 });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a conditional expression in an assignment

```
qtype = (qtype == "econo") ? "ecolo" : "econo";
```

or just a simple `if`:

```
if (qtype == "econo") {
    qtype = "ecolo";
} else {
    qtype = "econo";
}
```

For a true/false boolean variable, you can simply write:

```
variable = !variable;
```

the `!` operator performs the boolean *not* operation.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, Can I use same logic to toggle the true false boolean as well? by the way I still have to wait 10 minutes to accept you answer!

Comment: For a boolean you can just write `variable = !variable;`.